# Nested array observation in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I've got a somehow complex property I'd like to observe in Polymer.

The property contains *nested* arrays which don't seem to be supported for observation using `observers` as they seem to only work cleanly with only 1-level of nesting (i.e just one array in the prop).

Let this be an example:

```
  Polymer({
    is: 'house-component',

    properties: {

      house: {
        type: Object,
        value: {
          parents: [
            {
              name: "BigFoo",
              children: [
                { name: "SmallFoo", age: 12 },
                { name: "SmallBaz", age: 15 },
                { name: "SmallSid", age: 17 }
              ]
            },
            {
              name: "BigBaz",
              children: [
                { name: "SmallIda", age: 11 },
                { name: "SmallTed", age: 18 },
                { name: "SmallMoe", age: 16 }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

How would I monitor exclusively for the following operations (just examples):

- changes to age of *any* child.
- addition/removals of children for *any* parent.

**Ideally**, I could have something along these lines:

```
    observers: [
      "_childAgeChanged(house.parents.*.children.*.age)",
      "_childrenChanged(house.parents.*.children)"
    ],
```

---

This is what I currently use:

```
    observers: [
      "_childrenChanged(house.parents.*)" // basically observes almost everything
    ],
```

which provides me with *all* the changes to the parents as well.

To hack around what I currently use, I'm doing a lot of string-matching on the `changeRecord`'s `path` to see which path was actually changed and how, however it looks absolutely hideous.

Is there a better way to go about it without changing the data structure I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic bullet here, the wildcard character can only be used at the end of a path, so your best bet is what you're doing—specifying `house.parents.*` and filtering on `path`.

I'm sure there are other ways to do it, but it's not too bad if you use a pair of regexes in your observer:

```
var splicesRe = /house\.parents\.([^.]*)\.children\.splices/
var ageRe = /house\.parents\.([^.]*)\.children\.([^.]*)\.age/

var match;
match = change.path.match(splicesRe);
if (match) {
    var parentKey = match[1];
    childrenChanged(parentKey, change);
}
else {
    match = change.path.match(ageRe);
    if (match) {
        var parentKey = match[1];
        var childKey = match[2];
        var newAge = change.value;
        childAgeChanged(parentKey, childKey, change.value);
    }
}
```

(Could be more compact; I added named variables to clarify the contents of the match groups.)

Comment: Thanks, that's similar to what I currently use to get past this issue. I was wondering if there was an actual "official way"/silver-bullet of doing this.